# How to use JavaScript variable in Java or the opposite

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Quiz full-stack application and before starting the quiz the user has to input his first name and last name. After finishing the quiz I want to get User's data in MySQL(id,first_name,last_name, score).

I have a `var score = 0;` variable in JS, for every right answer it increments.

In Back-End I have a model

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "score")
    private int score;
}
```

And here is my MVC method that saves the user

```
@GetMapping("/saveUser")
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        userService.save(user);
        return "index";
    }
```

This method adds User in MySQL table.
For example

```
            ---------------------------------------------
            | id |  first_name  |  last_name  | score    |
           ---------------------------------------------- 
            | 1 |     John      |    Doe      | 0(by default)
```

Thus I want to save real score(in JavaScript) instead of 0;

Comment: Send the value from JavaScript to your Java controller with a manual HTTP request, or better known as AJAX.

Comment: Or by form submit

Answer (score 0):

I see your `saveUser` accepts `User` object.

`User` object has a field `score`. Javascript side just make sure to update `score` field with `javascript:score` variable.

Can create a hidden input tag in HTML and append score value before final submit.

Add below line inside your HTML form tag if you using.

```
<input type="hidden" id="score" name="score" >
```